# Python - updating class attribute (monkey patching?)?

Tags: python, odoo, monkeypatching, class-attribute

So there is a class called `Field` and it has class attribute `_slots`, this attribute is dictionary.

So it looks like this (that class also use custom `__metaclass__`):

```
class Field(object):

  _slots = {
    'key1': False,
    'key2': None,
    ...
}
```

Class content is too big to be pasted here, so I'm providing a link to it, [src](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/fields.py#L290)

Now I need that when you instantiate this class, it will have my custom key/value pair inside that attribute.

So I tried this (in my own module):

```
from openerp import fields

fields.Field._slots['custom_key'] = None
```

When I print after this assignment, then it shows me that I have set this key/value pair, but actually when that class is loaded, it never gets my `custom_key`. Though if I monkey patch some method, it works, but for class attribute it does not. Is it even possible to do that (or am I doing something wrong here?)?

Though if I write simple test scenario with my own simple class, like:

**(f.py file)**

```
class F(object):
    _t = {'a': 1}
```

**(other python file)**

```
import f

f.F._t['b'] = 10

f_new = f.F()
print f_new._t
```

Then this one works.

**Update**

I also tried this (modifying code directly) in `MetaField` class that is used as `__metaclass` for `Field` (still that is ignored when `Field` class uses `_slots`:

```
def __new__(meta, name, bases, attrs):
    """ Combine the ``_slots`` dict from parent classes, and determine
    ``__slots__`` for them on the new class.
    """
    base_slots = {}
    for base in reversed(bases):
        base_slots.update(getattr(base, '_slots', ()))

    slots = dict(base_slots)
    slots.update(attrs.get('_slots', ()))

    attrs['__slots__'] = set(slots) - set(base_slots)
    attrs['_slots'] = slots
    attrs['_slots']['custom_key'] = None  # <= Modification here
    return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, attrs)
```

Comment: The metaclass `MetaField` handles `_slots` during class creation. Monkey patching `_slots` in a ready class will not work because of that.

Comment: Hm, I was testing `MetaField` and tried to add my custom key/value in method `__new__`, but it does not work (even if I modify code directly there). I'll update what I tried in question.

Comment: I only glanced at `MetaField`, but to me it seems that if you wish to have a `Field` type with new `_slots`, use subclassing. Your modification prolly does not work because you add it after the `__slots__` has been assigned (and you shouldn't do it that way anyway, you'd be adding `'custom_key'` to all types created from the metatype).